# Delete array items if repeats more then once, Php

Tags: php

I have an array and it has repeating items. So I trying to delete item if it repeats. For example:

$links:

```
  string(35) "/mjr/semba-tower/outline/index.html"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "/mjr/mc-futsukaichi/outline/index.html"
  [2]=>
  string(31) "/mjr/chihaya/outline/index.html"
  [3]=>
  string(35) "/mjr/semba-tower/outline/index.html"
```

As you see 2 semba-towers in the array and I want to delete one of if. 
I tried this, but output returns 0 item.

```
$output = [];
        foreach(array_count_values($links) as $value => $count)
        {
            if($count == 1)
            {
                $output[] = $value;
            }
        }

        var_dump($output);
```

Any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: You can use the array_unique to remove duplicates. Eg: array_unique($links)

Comment: oh, this solved the problem so easyly.  @CCoder Thank you so much.

Comment: @CCoder although this is trivial, you should still post an answer, not a comment.

Comment: oh okey @Nick. Since the post is already answered, will follow from the next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Use the PHP array_unique() function`

You can use the PHP array_unique() function to remove the duplicate elements or vlaues form an array. If the array contains the string keys, then this function will keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all the subsequent keys.

```
$links = array(
    "/mjr/semba-tower/outline/index.html",
    "/mjr/mc-futsukaichi/outline/index.html",
    "/mjr/chihaya/outline/index.html",
    "/mjr/semba-tower/outline/index.html"
);

// Deleting the duplicate items
$result = array_unique($links);
print_r($result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => /mjr/semba-tower/outline/index.html [1] => /mjr/mc-futsukaichi/outline/index.html [2] => /mjr/chihaya/outline/index.html )
```